# Call function A inside function B on Codeigniter's controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller that have about 5-6 functions.

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
  //  some code written
}    
public function Add()
{
  //  Some code written
}
public function xyz()
{
  //  Some code written
  $this->abc();
}
public function abc()
{
  // Some code written
}
}
```

In `xyz` function, i want to call `abc` function.
Is this possible ? if so, how to call it ?

Comment: Why would you think it is not possible? did you even try it?

Comment: yes, i try this code but not run.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is possible, the code you have written is correct

```
public function xyz()
{
  //  Some code written
  $this->abc();     //This will call abc()
}
```

EDIT:

Have you properly tried this?

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {
    public function xyz()
    {
      $this->abc();
    }
    public function abc()
    {
      echo "I am running!!!";
    }
}
```

and call `register/xyz`

Comment: is it possible to call function of another controller to the different controller @Saravanan

Comment: @always-a-learner, you can refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter. As a best practice, if you have a common code to be accessed by both controllers, move it to library and access library from each controller.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter v4: If you are adding it inside a controller method then add return as well:

```
class MYCONTROLLER extends BaseController {

  public function one() {
    return $this->two('Hello!');
  }

  public function two($dummy) {
    echo $dummy;
  }

}
```