# How to call a controller from another controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to load a controller function from another controller function using codeigniter. What is the suitable way to do this so when call it url should  be changed also.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter).

Comment: You can not do that with standard codeigniter you need a third party add on called HMVC. https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: basically this is not how MVC functions if you want to call one controller to another then your code requires refactoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No You cant do it.

What you have to do it is create that function in model and call it through your controllers. So it will work fine.

***Ex***

**In Model**

```
function get_id()
{
   //some argument 
}
```

In **controller 1**

```
$this->Model_name->get_id()
```

In **controller 2**

```
$this->Model_name->get_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can (for version 2)

load like this below inside your controller

> $this->load->library('../controllers/whathever');

and call the following method:

> $this->whathever->functioname();