# Calling a method of a model from another controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having two controllers `hrcontroller` and `admincontroller`.

And models `hrmodel` and `adminmodel`.

It is possible to access a method in `hrmodel` from `admincontroller`. ?

Comment: similar question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `admincontroller` you just do this

```
$this->load->model('hrmodel'); 
$this->hrmodel->get_data(); 
//replace get_data for a real function on your model
```

you can load all models you want doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer did not work for me.
Heres what worked out for me:

> $this->load->model('hrcontroller/hrmodel'); 
>   $this->hrmodel->myfunction();

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this with CI is the following:

From your Controller do this:

```
$this->hrmodel->my_function('in case you wanna pass an argument, place it here.');
```

And on your Model do this:

```
function my_function('in case youre passing an argument.'){
    //Your functions behavior.
}
```