# I want to load a controller function from another controller function using codeigniter. What is the suitable way?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I wanna to send the data from first controller to second one. currently i am using redirect but i don't want use redirect and  don't want to take data with flash data is there any other way?

Comment: You need to clarify your intention more. This way, your questoiin is too broad to take advantage thinking of what exactly need to be solved. Also questions without propper code that follows those are not likely to be interested for most users want to help. Check [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) how to ask properly.

Comment: you can make core controller and extends controllers with first controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a controller from another controller in codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter)