# Different controller load changing from codeigniter 2 -> 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to move from codeigniter 2 to codeigniter 3.
Normally in most of our functions in our controller we call other controller sometimes like this,

```
 $this->load->controller('login');
 return $this->login->index();
```

But in codeigniter 3 this crashes, I checked how routes worked in this stack overflow question.

[How to load a controller from another controller in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

But the above url does not work for me, since changing routes will cancel all the database trasactions I use with mysql gets cancelled.

Is there a good solution to load different controller, I thought of moving it to a library and calling it like that but I think there is a better way. Also the HMVC might be a solution but its still doesn't solve the issue for a simple purpose.

Comment: If you need to call controllers with in controllers normal MVC does not work you need to add third party https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: This is a old tutorial but a good one to start one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ&list=PLBEpR3pmwCawDZ6FgNYoyvicEz4HrJPec the tutorial has step by step guides note though some things have changed since the tutorial was made like the class and file naming method etc in CI 3 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for HMVC solution. [Check This Out](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Update : 
By implementing HMVC, you can load any of your controller as a module like following

```
function abc(){
  $this->load->module("my_auth");
  $this->my_auth->check_login();
}
```

Comment: I did write in my question that HMVC is a solution, but a diffult one for me.

Comment: ahh!! I am sorry. I didnt see that. My bad.

Comment: No worries  :D  I don't want to use HMVC since that will take me 1 month to do for the amount of codes i have :'(

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you gave you cannot do that - I am not aware of the ability to `$this->load->controller` in CI3.

Your better option is to create a MY_Controller and extend your controllers from that and then place shared controller functions within that.

Comment: The link I gave was to show that routes might been an option, but it clearly isn't. Your solution does work but moving around 15000 lines of code is a very intensive task, there might be a easier solution to this. Hence the question.

Comment: In my own experience I have created myself a login library (noting the name of your controller) which I then pull into MY_Controller. IMHO a login controller should probably be a library - it will be more helpful in future projects as well.

Comment: Exactly! Thats one of the conclusions I came to as well. But I posted the question here thinking if there is someone with a better answer it would be very helpful :')