# Codeigniter: how to test library that takes Controller instance in constructor?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have the following Library called Item_service:

```
class Item_Service {
private $items;

function __construct(Items $items)
{
    $this->items = $items;
}
```

Where `Items` is an instance of `controllers/Items.php`.
In my test class called `Items_test.php` i try to load the `Item_service` library using the following line:

```
$items = $this->CI->load->library('items/Item_service');
```

But then I get error saying

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Item_Service::__construct() must be an instance of Items, null given
```

My test class is written based on `kenjis/ci-phpunit-test`.

How should I inject the controller into this library to be able to test the library? Also, can I test the controller itself? There are a lot of helper methods inside the controller.

Comment: @NikuNj Rathod - Why have you added additional code to the OP's question in your edit?

Comment: yes @MagnusEriksson . I just rejected that edit as it clearly conflicts with OP's intention

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to pass it within an array as the second param to the library call. So for example:

`library('items/Item_service',array('controller'=>$this->CI));`

Then from the construct of your service don't reference Items - it will be an array but then your Items will be available on the 'controller' key.

`$this->items = $items['controller'];`

Comment: In my case $this is NOT an instance of controller - it is an instance of Test Class

Comment: So would it not then be $this->CI?

Comment: $this->CI and then what? How to tell which controller to load?

Comment: But why don't you call this test from the controller itself and then $this->CI will reference that? If you want to test the controller - surely run the test from the controller itself?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895 which I believe is possibly the direct answer to your query but I reckon that you can solve your challenge but just by calling from the controller itself.

Comment: I am not trying to test a controller. I have a LIBRARY MyLibrary.php and this library has the folllowing constructor: `__construct(Controller controllerObject){$this->controllerObject = controllerObject)}`. I am trying to test this LIBRARY in my TEST class. But to be able to test it, I have to pass Controller object in constructor in my TEST class.

Comment: Then as per the answer 14165895 I'm not sure you can call controllers outside the main CI scope I'm afraid.