# Add code to function from another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter framework i have two controller files:
controllerA.php and controllerB.php

I need controllerB.php to add code in controllerA.php function

I have no idea how to do it, i checked Codeigniter manual, google and stackoverflow but was not able to find solution

controllerA.php has function:

```
function get_permission_conditions()
{
    return do_action('staff_permissions_conditions', [
        'contracts' => [
            'view'     => true,
            'view_own' => true,
            'edit'     => true,
            'create'   => true,
            'delete'   => true,

]);
}
```

I want controllerB.php to communicate with controllerA.php and add custom code example:

```
function get_permission_conditions()
{

//Code from controllerA.php
    return do_action('staff_permissions_conditions', [
        'contracts' => [
            'view'     => true,
            'view_own' => true,
            'edit'     => true,
            'create'   => true,
            'delete'   => true,

//custom code from controllerB.php goes here

]);
}
```

Comment: I think this link is userful for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter
Here show method of controller class extends to use function of other controller.

Comment: What is `do_action()`? Where does it come from?

Comment: what ever you are doing here - use a model / library for such purpose

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `controllerA` like this:

```
class controllerA extends CI_Controller{
    // All the function will go here
    return do_action('staff_permissions_conditions', [
        'contracts' => [
            'view'     => true,
            'view_own' => true,
            'edit'     => true,
            'create'   => true,
            'delete'   => true,

    ]); 
}
class controllerB extends controllerA{
    public $permission_array;
    function __construct() {
        $this->permission_array = $this->do_action();  // Here $permission_array will have the array returned by controllerA's function 'do_action'
    }

    //custom code from controllerB.php goes here
    // You can use $permission all over
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent controller for both of the and let them both extend that parent and move that method to that parent and let the parent extend `CI_Controller` .. pretty much like what you did with `MY_Controller` ...

That's your C_Controller (Parent controller):

```
class C_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // your methods that will be extended
    ...

}
```

That's your A_Controller:

```
class A_Controller extends C_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

That's your B_Controller:

```
class B_Controller extends C_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```