# Calling a controller from another controller in codeigniter (ERROR)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the Login_controller:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
    $usuario = $query->row();
    $this->load->library('../controllers/Dashboard_controller');
}
```

And I have the Dashboard_Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view("dashboard/Dashboard_view");          
}
}
```

But, I got a message error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Dashboard_controller::$load
>   Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
>   Line Number: 147
>   Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\application\controllers\Login_controller.php
>   Line: 34
>   Function: library
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Call to a member function helper() on null
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\system\libraries\Form_validation.php
>   Line Number: 147
>   Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\application\controllers\Login_controller.php
>   Line: 34
>   Function: library
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\acjum1\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: short answer: HMVC is not supposed to work this way. Controllers shouldn't call other controllers. You could redirect from one controller to another and pass data using flashdata, tempdata, regular session data (not recommended) or other means, but not invoke controllers from within other controllers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
redirect('/dashboard/index');
```

Comment: Calling one controller from another isn't really the same as redirecting the request.

Comment: Correct, but i guess he wants to load a new page so this will work

Comment: Indeed not the same but one should not end up doing this in the first place, a redirect should be good

Comment: Unless the OP needs the variable ($usuario) that was set before the redirect for something. We don't really know enough about the context.

Comment: He should do query's on a Model , normally i do it on a model not in the controller

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked before. 
Basically you are calling the controller but not the index function.
Please refer to : [How to load a controller from another controller in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Please don't write comments as answers. If the question has been asked and answered before, the question should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Please check the Dashboard_Controller instead Dashboard_controller  in library load