# How to run controller function on every request?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and have a controller Checkme.php and function inside talkcheck. Via url i can access it like http://site.com/checkme/talkcheck

I want this to run every time when codeigniter is loaded ( page requested ), how would I go with this?

I tried solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091100/codeigniter-load-controller-within-controller) but it overwrittes exiting object and half of my methods don't work

Comment: All you want to do is call the URL? Does it have to be in a controller or can you move it to a model/library/helper depending on function of it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) to run a function on every page load by setting `enable_hooks` to `TRUE` in config.php and adding the following code to `config/hooks.php`

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                            'class'    => 'Checkme',
                            'function' => 'talkcheck',
                            'filename' => 'Checkme.php',
                            'filepath' => 'controllers'
                            );
```