# Unable to locate the specified class when load controller inside controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to use controller **System** inside controller **Historic** because i have some problems with cron.

When i try to load like this:

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/system');
```

i get error:

```
Unable to locate the specified class: System.php
```

System.php class does not exists, there is **System** class in System.php file what i want to call from Historic.php controller.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just make an object of that System class.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer You think like this: $system = $this->load->library('../controllers/system'); ? This don't works. Same error

Comment: Ya it doesn't work.  Controller cant call as library

Comment: Like this : `$s = new System();` or `use System` at top of the file.

Comment: @DocNet just try this `$path = APPPATH.'/controllers/system';
$this->load->library($path);`

Comment: @Abdulla Now i get same error, but instead System.php now display System: Unable to load the requested class: System

Comment: @Mr.Engineer I already tried that, but that is inpossible.

Comment: @DocNet I just tld some try. Controller cant load as library

Comment: @Abdulla i check some answers and i see this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091100/codeigniter-load-controller-within-controller

check Zulqurnain abbas answer where peoples say that is possible.

Comment: Change this `$path = APPPATH.'/controllers/system';` to this `$path = APPPATH.'controllers/system';`

Comment: @Abdulla Nope, same again. Maybe last ci don't support load controller as libray? :/ What is alternative?

Comment: what is in that ?? and what kind of purpose of your usage with that??

Comment: In System is function that list all email's from table and send mail to all.
Now i want to run that with cron daily, but when i try 
index.php system runsystem it won't works. But index.php historic works great, so i want to call System function runsystem inside Historic index because cron can run that controller. System controller has some redirects in index() function so that maybe is reason why cron don't run it well, i need to have that redirects.

Comment: If your trying to load controller in to another controller use HMVC